# Button color change does not work on other computers

Tags: vb.net, winforms, button, timer

I have a strange problem that I can't seem to figure out. I have a timer that runs every 3 seconds and changes a button color to yellow, black, or green depending on if there are schedules pending, no schedules, or schedule currently running, respectively.

It works fine on my computer when I go into debug mode and add a schedule or have one run, it changes color like it should. I put this program onto a virtual machine and made the same schedule with the same data parameters, but the button doesn't change colors. I have .net 4.0 installed on both machines.

```
Public Sub createTimer()

        buttonTimer = New Timer()
        buttonTimer.Start()
        buttonTimer.Interval = 3000
        AddHandler buttonTimer.Tick, AddressOf buttonTimer_Tick
```

createTimer() is called from a runonce function when the page is loaded.

```
Public Sub buttonTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

  If Scheduler.AutomationRunning = True Then
       btnAutoStartMenu.ForeColor = Color.Green
  ElseIf Scheduler.AutomationRunning = False And Automation.ScheduleList.Count > 0 Then
       btnAutoStartMenu.ForeColor = Color.Yellow
  ElseIf Scheduler.AutomationRunning = False And Automation.ScheduleList.Count = 0 Then
       btnAutoStartMenu.ForeColor = Color.Black
  End If
```

I am wondering could it possibly be a dll I'm not including in the installer? But color change seems like something easily built into .net framework, so having 4.0 on both should take care of that correct?

EDIT:
Also, tried it on another virtual machine instance and the same problem remains.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to set the button colour?

Comment: Ok i posted the code. BTW, if I install it on the computer, it doesn't change color, yet when I run it debug mode within VS 2010, it works! On the same computer?  Is there some kind of dependency that I need to reference or include?  Very weird

Comment: what is the value of `Scheduler.AutomationRunning`? Check it out.

Comment: As well as the code in the current answer, add some more debugging after each `If` statement, and add an `Else` just for debugging too. If you can't explain the results, post them here.

Comment: A minor quibble, but I don't expect this to be a problem, especially because it's working in the IDE, move the `buttonTimer.Start()` after setting the `.Interval` and hooking up the event.

Answer (score 0):

@RoadBump is correct. What happens if `Scheduler` is `Nothing`?

You should get some more clue by adding some error handling:

```
Try
    If Scheduler.AutomationRunning = True Then
       btnAutoStartMenu.ForeColor = Color.Green
    ElseIf Scheduler.AutomationRunning = False And Automation.ScheduleList.Count > 0 Then
       btnAutoStartMenu.ForeColor = Color.Yellow
    ElseIf Scheduler.AutomationRunning = False And Automation.ScheduleList.Count = 0 Then
       btnAutoStartMenu.ForeColor = Color.Black
    End If
Catch ex as Exception
    btnAutoStartMenu.ForeColor = Color.Red
End Try
```

So if your button goes red then you need to start some further investigation